ADTK Visualization: ValueError: Multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is no longer supported
I have tried to reproduce the examples from anomaly detection tutorial: https://adtk.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebooks/demo.html#ThresholdAD
When I use this to plot:
from adtk.visualization import plot

it gives me an ValueError: Multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. obj[:, None]) is no longer supported. Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead.
I have checked similar issues with seaborn and possible solutions from those discussions (including Copilot and ChatGPT), though there are no cases with with adtk. I am using Python 3.10.7 on Windows 10. Here are the packages.
adtk            0.6.2
contourpy       1.2.1
cycler          0.12.1
fonttools       4.52.4
joblib          1.4.2
kiwisolver      1.4.5
matplotlib      3.9.0
numpy           1.26.4
packaging       24.0
pandas          2.2.2
patsy           0.5.6
pillow          10.3.0
pip             24.0
pyparsing       3.1.2
python-dateutil 2.9.0.post0
pytz            2024.1
scikit-learn    1.5.0
scipy           1.13.1
setuptools      63.2.0
six             1.16.0
statsmodels     0.14.2
tabulate        0.9.0
threadpoolctl   3.5.0
tzdata          2024.1

